# Converting a CSV file with double quotes to a pipe-delimited format using sed

Tags: bash, csv, unix, sed, delimited

I'm trying to convert CSV files into pipe-delimited text files.

Let's say I have a file called **sample.csv**:

`aaa",bbb"ccc,"ddd,eee",fff,"ggg,hhh,iii","jjj kkk","lll"" mmm","nnn"ooo,ppp"qqq",rrr" sss,"ttt,""uuu",Z`

I'd like to convert this into an output that looks like this:

`aaa"|bbb"ccc|ddd,eee|fff|ggg,hhh,iii|jjj kkk|lll" mmm|"nnn"ooo|ppp"qqq"|rrr" sss|ttt,"uuu|Z`

Now after tons of searching, I have come the closest using this **sed** command:

`sed -r 's/""/\v/g;s/("([^"]+)")?,/\2\|/g;s/"([^"]+)"$/\1/;s/\v/"/g'`

However, the output that I received was:

`aaa"|bbb"ccc|ddd,eee|fff|ggg,hhh,iii|jjj kkk|lll" mmm|"nnn"ooo|pppqqq|rrr" sss|ttt,"uuu|Z`

Where the expected for the 9th column should have been **ppp"qqq"** but the result removed the double quotes and what I got was **pppqqq**.

I have been playing around with this for a while, but to no avail.
Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Parsing such structures with a language like `sed` is going to be very painful. If you have the opportunity I would recommend looking into any CSV parsing library, such as [the one built into Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: As mentioned in the comment of the answer below, using a dedicated CSV parser was not bringing me the required output, which is why I had to resort to ```sed``` instead. But I'll try looking into your link and see if there is anything that can be done. Thanks a lot :))

Comment: Your requirements seem inconsistent, so I don't think you can get this with a simple regex. `perl -pe 's/(?:"(.*?)"|([^,]+)),/$1$2|/g'` comes close, but fails for `"nnn"ooo`.

Comment: To convert this csv file I would treat each line as a separate file i.e. replace all `,`'s by newlines. Then any lines that start with `"` but do not end in `"` could be  joined and their newlines replaced by `,`'s. For all lines, then replace `""` by `"` and remove any starting and ending `"`'s. The newlines remaining can then be replace by `|`'s. This seems to achieve most of what you want, however columns 8 and 9 in your expected result do not match up because col 8 starts with `"` but does not end with `"` until col 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with **sample.csv** is that it mixes non-quoted fields (containing quotes) with fully quoted fields (that should be treated as such).

You can't have both at the same time. Either all fields are (treated as) unquoted and quotes are preserved, or all fields containing a quote (or separator) are fully quoted and the quotes inside are escaped with another quote.

So, **sample.csv** should become:

```
"aaa""","bbb""ccc","ddd,eee",fff,"ggg,hhh,iii","jjj kkk","lll"" mmm","""nnn""ooo","ppp""qqq""","rrr"" sss","ttt,""uuu",Z
```

to give you the desired result (using a csv parser):

```
aaa"|bbb"ccc|ddd,eee|fff|ggg,hhh,iii|jjj kkk|lll" mmm|"nnn"ooo|ppp"qqq"|rrr" sss|ttt,"uuu|Z
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments `sed` or any other Unix tool is not recommended for this kind of complex CSV string. It is much better to use a dedicated CSV parser like this in PHP:

```
$s = 'aaa",bbb"ccc,"ddd,eee",fff,"ggg,hhh,iii","jjj kkk","lll"" mmm","nnn"ooo,ppp"qqq",rrr" sss,"ttt,""uuu",Z';
echo implode('|', str_getcsv($s));
```

```
aaa"|bbb"ccc|ddd,eee|fff|ggg,hhh,iii|jjj kkk|lll" mmm|nnnooo|ppp"qqq"|rrr" sss|ttt,"uuu|Z
```

Comment: The 8th column is exactly why switched away from a proper CSV parser. It gives me ```nnnooo``` when I actually need ```"nnn"ooo```. Thanks a lot for replying :))

Comment: ok then please edit your question and list all the rules for your custom CSV parsing.

Comment: Sure, I'll work on it. By the way, the rest of your answer was pretty much bang on, except for the mentioned 8th column.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem.
I found right result with https://www.papaparse.com/demo
Here is a FOSS on github. So maybe you can check how it works.
With the source of [ "aaa""","bbb""ccc","ddd,eee",fff,"ggg,hhh,iii","jjj kkk","lll"" mmm","""nnn""ooo","ppp""qqq""","rrr"" sss","ttt,""uuu",Z ]
The result appears in the browser console:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB5OM.png